# UI Bootstrap datepicker disable keyboard support

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

According to UI Bootstrap's official documentation [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), the datepicker component supports keyboard events. However, I have to disable up and down arrow key events. Normally, up and down arrows open datepicker-popup and I should disable this. The documentation does not say anything about this, and I didn't found anything on the web.

I tried the following to disable key events:

```
<input datepicker-popup shortcut-propagation="true"...
```

But that must be disabling all key events, and it didnt work either. How can I disable specific key events?